# Displaying Excel Userform without opening file

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a Userform, currently I am using this code  to hide Excel and just show the userform (Code was place in Workbook)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Application.Visible = False
 ricwin.Show
End Sub
```

The issue I am facing is that in ocassions  the excel file will open but not as macro enable, and I require to close it  and reopen it so the macro runs.

Also is there a chance to display a taskbar icon for the userform without an excel file  being in background?

Comment: You have to open the file to show the form

Comment: I was able to  "hide" excel and just show the userform,    but sometimes it bugs and shows excel

Comment: In that workbook, run the line `ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False` and then save the workbook. Now you can open it and run the userform and the workbook will never be visible. No need to worry about turning the application invisible or anything complicated.

Comment: I'd just setup the workbook so that there's a form control button to launch the UserForm if it doesn't start up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by adding a ToggleButton to the userform. When the workbook is opened, the worksheet is hidden, only the userform is shown. For this, the following codes are added to **a **module****:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Application.Visible = False
UserForm1.Show
UserForm1.ToggleButton1.Value = False
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA306.gif)

[Source of sample file](https://eksi30.com/the-updated-excel-userform/)